# Form change best practice

Tags: forms, symfony

In my template I have a **country** select box, and **province** element which changed dynamically based on **country**. For example, If I select United States, Province will be a selectbox which include US States. If i select other country, Province will be only a text field. I know that I have to do that by Javascript but I want to know the best practice in this case. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use Javascript to show either the select box with provinces or a text input field. If you want to have different provinces lists depending on the chosen country you could use AJAX and load a proper list of provinces whenever the country changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question arises almost daily on stackoverflow ... How to handle sub-select's like country->state ...?

Best practice for multiple related select field types is **only** loading the **first selectbox** from database with a dedicated submit button for adding the subselects - could be "show states" or similar in your case.

**Don't fetch** all the **possible sub-selects** when rendering the form **the first time**. This could easily lead to **heavy database queries** if you show something like country -> state -> city for example ... but country -> state for all countries is already too much.

If the form was submitted using the "show states" button add the related sub-select to the form together with either a "show cities" button or if no other sub-selects will be loaded .. with the final "save" button.

This way a user without JavaScript can use the double-select without the at first unneeded subselect queries involved. Just hiding the second select with JS is **not** best practice.

**Progressive enhancement** through JavaScript would then be **AJAX**-Loading i.e. a **JSON** list of the states for a country, removing the "show states" button , rendering the data using **JS templating** engines like handlebars or mustache and adding the "save" button.

This way you don't have to send too much repetetive data to the client browser ( option,option,option ... ).

Last step would be caching client and server-side to speed up the loading times - maybe even involve some kind of background preloading i.e. the top 5 choices for the client's preferred language.